# Google Cloud Vision OCR Error Code 7 - Permission Denied

Tags: node.js, ocr, google-cloud-vision

I am building a webapp that utilizes Google Cloud Vision's OCR. The OCR works fine for about 7-8 requests, after which I get an error like so:

```
Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: Your application has authenticated using end user credentials from the Google Cloud SDK or Google Cloud Shell which are not supported by the vision.googleapis.com. We recommend configuring the billing/quota_project setting in gcloud or using a service account through the auth/impersonate_service_account setting. For more information about service accounts and how to use them in your application, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/.
```

The problem is, I have already set up a billing account and a service account.

I have tried using multiple GCloud commands to fix this, and when I run `gcloud auth list`, I can see that my service account is the active account. I have also tried generating a JSON key and setting path to that key in my enviroment variables - as instructed here: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started

Has anyone encountered this issue before? For reference, I am running Windows 10 and using Node.js for the webapp. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are authenticating using end user credentials from the Google Cloud SDK or Google Cloud Shell and not service account credentials.

1.Make a new directory

```
mkdir ocr
cd ocr
```

2.Download an image.

```
curl https://www.python.org/static/apple-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png > image.png
```

3.Install the client library.

```
sudo pi3 install --upgrade google-cloud-vision
```

4.Create a service account.

```
gcloud iam service-accounts create ocr-vision \
      --description "ocr-vision" \
      --display-name "ocr-vision"

gcloud iam service-accounts list
```

5.Create a key.json file.

```
gcloud iam service-accounts keys create key.json \
      --iam-account ocr-vision@your-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

6.Assign the owner role to the service account.

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding your-project \
      --member serviceAccount:ocr-vision@your-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
      --role roles/owner
```

7.Export the env variable

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=key.json
```

8.Run the script

```
 python script.py
```

```
import io
import os
# Imports the Google Cloud client library
from google.cloud import vision
from google.cloud.vision import types
# Instantiates a client
client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

# The name of the image file to annotate
file_name = os.path.abspath('image.png')

# Loads the image into memory
with io.open(file_name, 'rb') as image_file:
    content = image_file.read()

image = types.Image(content=content)

# Performs label detection on the image file
response = client.label_detection(image=image)
labels = response.label_annotations

print('Labels:')
for label in labels:
    print(label.description)
```

9.Output

```
Labels:
Yellow
Font
Line
Material property
Clip art
Logo
Symbol
Icon
Graphics
Illustration
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I just used the gcloud commands you provided it's solved my problem.